SwiftData returning "Non-Sendable" array of objects from a struct
I have a MovieData class that conforms to SwiftData model as @Model such as:
@Model
class MovieData: Codable{
   var ....
}

We also have a web service struct that returns a MovieData array from an API:
struct WebService {
    
    func getMoviesArr() async -> [MovieData]{
        do {
            let data = try await getDataFromURL(callType: .movies)
            return try JSONDecoder().decode([MovieData].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch movies arr: \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
}

The issue I am facing is, while importing the movies list to save them using SwiftData on a background actor created by @ModelActor the error is obviously Non-sendable type '[MovieData]' returned by implicitly asynchronous call to nonisolated function cannot cross actor boundary
As SwiftData models cannot conform to the Sendable protocol I cannot use a seperate class/struct to better organize the code and make more modular.
Calling the struct and the method from my actor:
@ModelActor
actor UpdateActor: Sendable{

    func downloadAndWriteMovies(context: ModelContext) async -> [MovieData]{
        let webService = WebService()

        let moviesArr = await webService.getMoviesArr() \\ <- Creating the error
            
        context.insert(moviesArr)

        return moviesArr
    }

}

Any ideas how to go around it instead of putting all the code in our @ModelActor or create extensions for that actor?

One solution is to just save the data and not return it and then fetch it afterwards. Just saw the edit, why is the actor sendable?

@JoakimDanielson the issue with that approach is that I would like to modify the data before inserting it, which would be possible with that approach but seems very redundant, especially when working with very large lists/data structures

Well you can’t pass model objects outside of an actor’s boundaries as the message says. Two options, merge the actor and the api functionality into one type (actor) so nothing needs to be passed across any boundaries or decode into a separate struct type that can be safely passed around. Personally I have opted for the latter and I am working with struct types and none of my (relevant) model classes conforms to Codable.

As Joakim Danielson says, don't decode to your @Model class. Write some Sendable
structs that contains all the information you need to create your @Model class, and decode to those structs instead. These are not "redundant" - this is how you make your code thread safe.
